# Alternating Total

Tags: list-manipulation

Any cleaner solutions than what I came up with? (Maybe by multiplying every other entry by -1)

```
altTotal[x_] := Total@x[[;; ;; 2]] - Total@x[[2 ;; ;; 2]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
altTotal3[x_] := Total@x - 2 Total@x[[2 ;; ;; 2]]
```

is a bit faster.

Comment: That is a very nice example for floating point arithmetic being significantly faster than memory operations.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe

```
altTotal2[x_] := Subtract @@ Total[Partition[x, 2]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
altTotal4[x_] := Total@Developer`PartitionMap[Subtract @@ # &, x, 2]
```

**Edit:** `altTotal4` is quite surprisingly slow.  The following `Fold` is much better but still not competititve.

```
altTotal5[x_] := First@Fold[With[{s = #1[[2]]}, {s*#2 + #1[[1]], -s}] &, {0, 1, -1}, x]
```

Comment: That's slower by more than two orders of magnitude than `altTotal3`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to take + and - each successive member using Riffle:

```
altTotal5[x_]:=Total[x Riffle[ConstantArray[1, Length[x]], -1][[1 ;; Length[x]]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

"Maybe" goes as below:

```
altTotal4 = SparseArray[{i_?EvenQ -> -1}, Length[#], 1].# &
```

Or

```
altTotal5[x_] := Total@MapIndexed[(-1)^(1 + First[#2]) # &, x]
```